# NullInjectorError: No provider for MediaMatcher

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am working with Angular 5 and AngularMaterial2.

I have an error when I try to inject the MediaMatcher service.

I have two modules. The root module that it is for the app bootstrap, and the main module that contains all the components. I am trying to use a responsive side nav as the example of angular material documentation says.

I suppose I have a missing import, but I cannot find what is the module.

Here's my code:

**AppModule:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

//Angular Module Dependencies
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

//Root Module Imports
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

//Feature Module Imports
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CoreModule  } from "./core-module/core.module";
import { MainModule } from './main-module/main.module';
import { FrontSession } from './core-module/services/front-session.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    //Dependencies
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

    //Features
    CoreModule.forRoot({ devMode: true }),
    MainModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ],  
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**MainModule:**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

    import { MatButtonModule, MatCardModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatTableModule, MatSidenavModule, MatIconModule, MatToolbarModule, MatListModule } from '@angular/material'; 
    const matModules = [  MatButtonModule, MatCardModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatTableModule, MatSidenavModule, MatIconModule, MatToolbarModule, MatListModule ];

    import { Home } from './states/home/home.component';
    import { Login } from './states/login/login.component';
    import { Signin } from './states/signin/signin.component';

    import { UserEdit } from './components/user-edit/user-edit.component';
    import { UserList } from './components/user-list/user-list.component';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        matModules
      ],
      declarations: [ Home, Login, Signin, UserEdit, UserList ]
    })

    export class MainModule { }
```

**HomeComponent:**

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MediaMatcher } from '@angular/cdk/layout';


@Component( { 
    templateUrl: './home.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.css'] 
})
export class Home 
{
    mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;



constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, media: MediaMatcher){ }

   }
```

Comment: https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import the `LayoutModule` in your `MainModule`. The `MediaMatcher` is provided by the module.

This would work, but you would provide another instance of the service:

```
...,
providers: [
    MediaMatcher
],
...
```

Comment: You don't have to `provide` it. By the way, the property is actually `providers`, not `provide`.

Comment: import {LayoutModule} from '@angular/cdk/layout' // then add it to imports array of your app @NgModule decorator. If its sub module which you imported further in app module, you need to export it as well.